# How can I diff two files with full context?

Tags: unix, command-line, diff

I have two files with slight differences.  A normal `diff` will show me the differences between the files.  With `-c` or `-u` I can add an amount of context to each hunk.  What options can I pass to `diff` to see every unchanged line alongside the changes, and get the diff as a single, large hunk?

Comment: If you happen to know a bound on the size of the files, how about just passing a large argument to -U? diff -U 9999 ...

Comment: Or simply `diff -U -1` as pointed out by J-L

Comment: @GunarGessner noted below as well, but `-U -1` no longer works in diffutils 3.8 (tagged in August 2021, underlying change https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/commit/src/diff.c?id=8d26b1403e8607811ccebdfe2822f2dad42a36d3)

Comment: From reading the source code, for `-U -1`, the `-1` became `CONTEXT_MAX`, which was defined as `(LIN_MAX - 1) / 2`, where `LIN_MAX` was defined as `PTRDIFF_MAX`, which on (mainstream) 64-bit platforms is `INT64_MAX`. Hence, `-U 1` was equivalent to `-U 4611686018427387903` on 64-bit platforms. On 32-bit platforms, it was equivalent to `-U 1073741823` instead.

Comment: You may want to give `dwdiff` a try, e.g. `dwdiff -w "$(echo -e '\x1b[1;9m\x1b[1;91m')" -x "$(echo -e '\x1b[0m\x1b[K')" -y "$(tput bold; tput setaf 2)" -z "$(tput sgr0)" file1 file2`."

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the "-y" option for full side by side output

diff -y file1 file2

Will give you output something like

```
* Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.     * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
* Praesent fringilla facilisis pede.                            * Praesent fringilla facilisis pede.
* Nulla sit amet tellus id massa luctus pellentesque.           * Nulla sit amet tellus id massa luctus pellentesque.
* Pellentesque a neque nec elit aliquam congue.                 * Pellentesque a neque nec elit aliquam congue.
* Quisque rhoncus ultricies elit.                               * Quisque rhoncus ultricies elit.
* Pellentesque laoreet urna id arcu.                            * Pellentesque laoreet urna id arcu.
* Aenean non erat et elit egestas dictum.                       * Aenean non erat et elit egestas dictum.
* Proin ornare sem eget nulla.                                  * Proin ornare sem eget nulla.
* Phasellus placerat convallis elit.                            * Phasellus placerat convallis elit.
* Donec ultricies metus non purus.                              * Donec ultricies metus non purus.
* Sed vel enim et nunc accumsan egestas.                        * Sed vel enim et nunc accumsan egestas.
* Cras eget elit in purus luctus ornare.                        * Cras eget elit in purus luctus ornare.
* In pharetra ligula sodales pede.                            <
* Morbi consectetuer mi vitae sem.                              * Morbi consectetuer mi vitae sem.
* Donec sollicitudin pretium erat.                              * Donec sollicitudin pretium erat.
* Cras facilisis nunc sed leo.                                  * Cras facilisis nunc sed leo.
* Nunc varius ante sed nisi.                                    * Nunc varius ante sed nisi.
                                                              > THIS SHOULDN'T BE HERE
                                                              > THIS SHOULDN'T EITHER!
* Aenean in quam sagittis est ornare ultricies.                 * Aenean in quam sagittis est ornare ultricies.
* Etiam dignissim scelerisque velit.                            * Etiam dignissim scelerisque velit.
* Mauris porta fringilla sapien.                                * Mauris porta fringilla sapien.
* Proin vitae nisl vitae mauris viverra tempor.                 * Proin vitae nisl vitae mauris viverra tempor.
* Maecenas quis arcu sed lorem mollis bibendum.                 * Maecenas quis arcu sed lorem mollis bibendum.
* Morbi sed turpis non risus molestie posuere.                | * Morbi sed non risus molestie posuere.
* Curabitur id magna in nulla commodo tristique.                * Curabitur id magna in nulla commodo tristique.
* Praesent quis nulla vel augue faucibus viverra.             | * Praesent quis nulla BAD vel augue faucibus viverra.
* Sed interdum libero.                                        | * Sed lacinia interdum libero.
                                                              > ANOTHER ADDITION
* Donec ultricies posuere arcu.                                 * Donec ultricies posuere arcu.
* Etiam interdum auctor mi.                                     * Etiam interdum auctor mi.
```

Answer (score 36):

You can also override the diff formatting behavior to get your desired behavior without using side-by-side mode:

```
diff --new-line-format='+%L' --old-line-format='-%L' --unchanged-line-format=' %L' file1 file2
```

This command will show you the full file as context and be closest in format to `diff -u file1 file2`

Comment: Thanks for this answer - any idea how to add a hunk to that? I want to use `diff2html.py`, which accepts unified diff; and I have to manually say: `(echo -e "--- _L.txt\n+++ _R.txt\n@@ -1,100 +1,100 @@" && diff --new-line-format ... _L.txt _R.txt) | python diff2html.py > LR.html` to force its syntax coloring; however I just arbitrarily add the hunk numbers there until it starts working - and I'd rather `diff` output a hunk for that. Is it possible? Cheers!

Comment: This got a merge-conflict-like format exactly like I wanted! `diff --new-line-format="$(printf '======= test1.txt\n%%L>>>>>>>')" --old-line-format="$(printf '<<<<<<< test2.txt\n%%L')" --unchanged-line-format='%L' test1.txt test2.txt`

Comment: If you really need "unified" format you will need to add the `---/+++/@@` header lines yourself.

Answer (score 33):

The solution is to set a context size (-U argument) which is larger than the file itself:

```
diff -U 1000000 file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Note, this does not output anything for files with no differences. This is inconvenient if you need to do this for a whole bunch of files where some may have no changes at all

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  A quick note:  On my machine, instead of `-U 1000000`, I can just use `-U -1` and not have to worry about using a number that is large enough.  (I'm not sure why this is; maybe it's because -1 evaluates to a huge unsigned number.)  This is still subject to the same problem that @raarts brought up -- that it does nothing for files with no differences.

Comment: @J-L `-U -1` no longer works in diffutils 3.8 (tagged in August 2021, underlying change https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/commit/src/diff.c?id=8d26b1403e8607811ccebdfe2822f2dad42a36d3) :/