# generating .diff file with complete code from svn eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, diff

when i generate .diff file from eclipse using

**Java Editor -> Right click -> Team -> Create Patch**

I am getting .diff file only displaying the lines of modified changes. I want to generate the .diff file with complete code of that file. Any solution for this?

Comment: Are you on UNIX? You have very similar SO questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983669/svn-diff-to-output-all-lines-from-files and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354526/how-can-i-diff-two-files-with-full-context.

Comment: i am using windows. Thanks for the links :) it will really help me. just for a curiosity, Is it possible to get the .diff file with full line from eclipse instead of using command ?

Comment: i tried this command `svn diff > descriptive_name_of_patch.diff` but this produces only lines of modified changes. When i tried this command `svn diff --diff-cmd diff -x "-U30" > descriptive_name_of_patch.diff` i am getting `svn: E720087: Can't start process 'diff': The parameter is incorrect.` How to provide external diff ??

Answer (score 1):

You have asked in a comment: *How to provide external diff?*

Install [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) as external diff tool.

Then, create .bat file (make sure you pass correct path to WinMerge exe):

```
start "WinMerge" /B /WAIT "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" /e /ub /dl %3 /dr %5 %6 %7
```

and save it for example at

> c:\wm.bat

Then pass .bat file as argument: `svn diff --diff-cmd c:\wm.bat`

Which will open up WinMerge and show you the differences with complete file code.

More info can be found at this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/569281/1023562).

Comment: hi., this command opens the winmerge with complete code but if i save it as diff file , i am getting only the file path in xml format.

Comment: How do you save the file? WinMerge > File > Save Right > Save as...?

Comment: I want to send this diff file for code review.. I saved it as project. If i use the save right option, will it be helpful code review?

Comment: Tools > Generate report? It will export both sides in HTML format - not sure if that fits your needs.

Comment: hi ivan. thanks for you solutions, but this generates HTML file. I need a diff file with complete code. The code review tool accepts only diff format :(

Comment: As you suggested this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983669/svn-diff-to-output-all-lines-from-files] provides a solution to mention the number of lines to be included in diff. I could see that it also uses the external diff. How to use that for windows?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (TortoiseSvn on windows) and I solved it by downloading [GetGnuWin32.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getgnuwin32/files/latest/download?source=files) and then following the directions in readme.txt to install it. I installed it in

> Downloads\GetGnuWin32

directory. Then I opened command window in the folder and added path to diff.exe on the system Path variable as : `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\tbudukh\Downloads\GetGnuWin32\gnuwin32\bin`. 

Then ran the command: `svn diff --diff-cmd=diff -x -U999999 > patch.diff`

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by installing external diff tool called **GnuWin32** and configured its path in **TortoiseSvn -> Settings**. Look for Merge Tool and select the option as external and provide the path of GnuWin32.

Now use the svn command as `svn diff --diff-cmd diff -x -U1000 > filename.diff`. This will produce diff file with 1000 lines of context. Increase -U value if your file is longer than 1000 lines. now diff file can be uploaded in any code review tool with full context.